# Let $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$. Can we convert matrix $A$ to matrix $B$ by elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Can we convert  matrix $A$ to matrix  $B$ by elementary row operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no. Consider $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

More in detail, row operations do not change $\ker A$.

Comment: Let both have full rank. is statement true?

Comment: @Tp-link If the matrix is $m\times n$ with $m\ge n$, yes.

Comment: Please more guide.

Comment: The answer to that is lengthy. Two $(m\times n)$-matrices $A,B$ are equivalent by row operations if and only if there is an invertible $(m\times m)$-matrix $P$ such that $PA=B$. Since $m\ge n$ and the matrix is full rank, the columns are linearly independent. Hence, such a matrix exists. You should find something of sort in any linear algebra book.

Comment: Please introduce a reference.

Comment: Please more help.

Comment: No, I'm done with it.